# Scrapy - Scraping hidden elements

Tags: xpath, scrapy, css-selectors

I think what I want to ask if it's possible to get around sql:hide (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sqlxml-annotated-xsd-schemas-using/hiding-elements-and-attributes-by-using-sql-hide?view=sql-server-2017), but I've described my actual problem below in case I'm mistaken:

I'm trying to scrape the "foo" urls from a website with a DOM similar to the following:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <a href="foo1">...</a>
                <a href="foo2">...</a>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <a href="bar1">...</a>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <a href="bar2">...</a>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Whenever I try `print(response.css('a'))` or equivalently `print(response.xpath('//a'))`, I can see the "foo" urls, but not the "bar" urls. Additionally, using XPath I can access up to the table, but `print(response.xpath('//table//*'))` and `print(response.xpath('//table//a'))` both output `[]`.

Could it be possible that the elements of table have been hidden from Scrapy somehow? How would one resolve this?

Thanks in advance. This is mainly for interest as the urls have a predictable pattern anyway.

Comment: Can you provide a link to an file that uses this feature? Scrapy does not care about the DOM, it cares about the underlying XML/HTML data. What matters here is where in that data are those links, if they are in that data at all.

Comment: The pages I was trying to scrape were behind HTTP authentication, so I don't think I could share them here. Could the inspect element tool not be showing me the actual HTML data? Is there any better way to view the HTML data?

Comment: Could you inspect the HTML you get after the authentication, and try to provide a short HTML file, based on the one you get, embedded in your question, that can be used to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is just a wild guess, but you can try

```
//a[starts-with(@href,'foo')]/text()
```

This should give you the text values of all `a` tags which have a `href` attribute which value starts with the string 'foo'.

---

But it could be possible that some parts of the result XML/HTML are loaded by JavaScript at a later time what would explain your difficulties locating certain elements.